# PHP / mySQL output via javascript and dropdown

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Here is what I have in php:

```
[Color, Size, Status]
Red, Small, 1
Red, Large, 0
Blue, Small, 1
Blue, Large, 1
```

I can get that output in php just fine like mentioned above. What I want to do is get this structured properly for dropdown in html and javascript/jquery (please continue reading for javascript purpose).

Basically there would be 2 dropdowns. One for Size and one for Color. The reason for javascript (preferably jquery) is to check the status. 1 means in stock and 0 for out of stock. So if someone were to select the combination of Red Color in Large Size it would be status of 0 (meaning out of stock)

I have been struggling on how to do this for few hours. Any help is much appreciated!!

----== UPDATE ==----

I have found a way to do this, but different than I had initially wanted to (using an array or ojbect in javascript)

Anyhow, my solution is posted here: http://jsbin.com/osipe5/2

Basically I output a bunch of combinations in a hidden input and then use the javascript to read them and update the text of the select options

Answer (score -1):

I'd have PHP also generate a javascript object of the data:

```
var inventory = { red: { small: 1, large: 0 }, blue: { small: 1, large: 1 } };
```

You could then check it with something like this:

```
quantity = inventory['red']['small']; // = 1
```

Comment: Thanks but the problem is how to properly generate the html (drop down code) and connect it to javascript?